# CSS issue: Chrome adds 3px extra margin-right to text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

[image]

I have 3 text fields. Each of them has margin-right: 5px. Google Chrome automatically adds 3-4px on margin-right into each element. I don't know how to fix this. I notice this because when I use JQUERY to generate more text fields on click event. I don't see these extra margin. These extra margin added only when the elements are rendered from my HTML, not from the string in my Javascript. Any idea? Thanks.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="text_input" name="field_class_0" />
<input type="text" class="text_input" name="field_book_title_0" />
<input type="text" class="text_input" name="field_isbn_0" />
```

CSS:

```
.text_input {
margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
padding: 5px 7px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3g42rjdp/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although, this may be dependent on the browser version, Chrome generally have these CSS rules for the `input` element:

```
-webkit-appearance: textfield;
background-color: white;
border-image-source: initial;
border-image-slice: initial;
border-image-width: initial;
border-image-outset: initial;
border-image-repeat: initial;
-webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
-webkit-user-select: text;
cursor: auto;
padding: 1px;
border: 2px inset;
```

and these for the `input`, `textarea`, `keygen`, `select`, `button`:

```
text-rendering: auto;
color: initial;
letter-spacing: normal;
word-spacing: normal;
text-transform: none;
text-indent: 0px;
text-shadow: none;
display: inline-block;
text-align: start;
margin: 0em 0em 0em 0em;
font: 13.3333px Arial;
```

and this for `input`, `textarea`, `keygen`, `select`, `button`, `meter`, `progress`:

```
-webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
```

So, this does not relate to the browser stylesheet rules.

## UPDATE

If you add a white-space like

- space
- tab
- newine ( **This is your case** )

between them, a gap will appear.

Depending on the situation, you can use either of the following methods to get rid of the gap:

- Add a negative `margin-left`
- Use float
- Remove the **whitespace** between the elements, which can be done:

  1- Put theme in one line

  ```
  <input type="text"><input type="text"><input type="text">
  ```

  2- Removing the space ( Don't worry, it is correct! :) )

  ```
  <input type="text"><
  input type="text"><
  input type="text">
  ```

  3- Use HTML comments

  ```
  <input type="text"><!--
  --><input type="text">
  ```

  I suggest you to use the **Number 1** method (Put theme in one line), but either will work.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but how can I fix this?

Comment: U R welcome. no, the above rules are defaults of Google Chrome. Please try to edit your question and add a more widen range of HTML elements around `input`s, with the relating CSS rules to help me improve my answer.

Comment: @LouisTran I found the problem, please check my updated answer, in a minute

Comment: @LouisTran the answer is updated, please check it and let me know if you are OK

Comment: You are correct! the line break causes the space. You are the man. Thank you very much. ^^ Hope my question and your answer help other people.